# ggplot: how to use scale_fill_discrete and change colours without overriding the set scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

My ggplot code looks like that:

```
t <- ggplot(df, aes(fill= Faktor2, y=Analysis, x=Faktor)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", width = 0.4) +
  theme_bw() + ylab("Analysis") + xlab("Fator")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
  labs(fill ="Other") +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c("A", "B", "C", "D",
                                          "F", "G"))

t + scale_fill_manual(values = mycolors)
t + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Spectral")
```

I used scale_fill_discrete, so that certain items of my legend are removed.
But now, when I change the color, the scales gets overwritten.
I also tried it with the

```
scale_fill_hue function()
```

but that doesn't work either.

I know it is better reproducible when I also provide you the data, but it is actually a kind of complex data, which merges several repetitions with an columns of an already existing one.

So I hoped there is just one easy fix how I can adjust the colours using the scale_fill_discrete function.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Use the breaks argument you currently have in `scale_fill_discrete()` into either `scale_fill_manual()` or `scale_fill_brewer()`, whichever one you want to actually use.

Comment: There's your answer.  Your `scale_fill_discrete()` can be replaced by `scale_fill_brewer()`, and just add the `breaks=` argument into `scale_fill_brewer()`.

Comment: @Phil, I'm trying to do a similar thing but with changing the x axis labels, and just using the labels=c argument is not working for me

Comment: @sscoresby Please ask a separate question with a reproducible data frame and code in order to get better help.